# Virtual Box guest (Windows7) in Ubuntu 12.04 (host) not connecting to the internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dns, dhcp

I have an Virtual Box running Win7 inside an Ubuntu host. The guest can not connect to the internet while the host can.

It is using an Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop adapter with settings set to autodetect.

The IP config file reads:

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : pm-PC
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-6F-3B-61 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d84:5fe5:a614:189a%11(Preferred) 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0 
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 30 August 2013 10:24:35 AM 
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, 31 August 2013 10:24:35 AM 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2 
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2 
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 235405351 
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-A7-5C-10-08-00-27-85-BD-42 
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2 
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D7033CB4-CF6A-4828-8004-6BD8242C3E58}:

```
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface 
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No 
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes 
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2048:166f:f5ff:fdf0(Preferred) 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2048:166f:f5ff:fdf0%13(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : :: 
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to do anything special to get internet to work in your guest, these are the settings that I have used for several years.[image]

Here is a link to networking for virtualbox that should help.
[networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Comment: Thanks, yes, these are the settings I have, but cannot detect whether the problem is Win-based, VB-based, or Ubuntu.. so trying to trouble shoot the issue...

Comment: I added a link that should help.

Comment: Thank you, I had seen the link and instructions, that is why I am asking for help - I can't see where I went wrong.